# Mouse click not working while debugging with GDB

Tags: 20.04, window, gdb

I'm trying to debug a windowed application with GDB in Ubuntu.

First I set a breakpoint in the code.

Then, while running the windowed application, the program stops at the breakpoint at some time.

When that happens, even though the mouse cursor can move freely, clicking doesn't work (left-click, right-click, middle-click and mouse wheel - none of them work).

The keyboard works fine I can type, I can Alt+Tab, etc.

This makes makes debugging very hard. Have you experienced this problem? What can I do?

My application is using SDL2. I have tried [this script](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/debugging-with-sdl-capturemouse/31014/3) but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using SDL version 2.0.20 (others may work, but I have found this issue on 2.0.22) **and** make sure that `SDL_CaptureMouse` has not been enabled before your breakpoint. Some libraries like certain branches of imgui might enable it whenever the mouse is down and this causes a lot of trouble.

Edit: Maybe don't use the latest version of SDL2. Try 2.0.20.

Comment: This was a long time ago, but it might help other people. You mentioned ImGui and that lit  up something in my head: I think I was indeed trying to debug something happening when I pressed a button in ImGui. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread, but I struggled with this.
Installing xdotool fixed it for me.